# How to transform Json to json by using XSLT in Java

Tags: json, xslt

Transform Json to Json by using XSLT in Java

I tried with taking input as Json. but unable to transform it through XSLT in Java

Comment: Which processor? Saxon 11 or 12? It has e.g. https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/JsonBuilder.html to parse the input JSON into an XdmValue which you can feed to the Xslt30Transformer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 3.0 has basically two ways to transform JSON to JSON; it can represent JSON objects and arrays as XDM maps and arrays and transform such maps and arrays into new maps/arrays and serialize them as JSON; it can also use the existing functions `json-to-xml` to transform some input JSON into the XML representation of JSON the XSLT 3.0 specification (and the XPath 3.1 spec) define to then do a normal XML to XML transformation to some representation of a different JSON structure to finally call `xml-to-json` to convert/serialize the transformed XML to JSON text/string again.

With Saxon (current version is 12) you can do it both ways, let's assume we have an input sample JSON

```
[
  {
    "Category 1" : "Marine",
    "Date 1"     : "31/03/2003",
    "Date 2"     : "31/12/2021",
    "Paid"       : 10,
    "OS"         : 4
  },
  {
    "Category 1" : "Marine",
    "Date 1"     : "31/03/2003",
    "Date 2"     : "31/12/2021",
    "Paid"       : 13,
    "OS"         : 5
  },
  {
    "Category 1" : "Marine",
    "Date 1"     : "31/12/2021",
    "Date 2"     : "31/03/2022",
    "Paid"       : 2,
    "OS"         : 5
  },
  {
    "Category 1" : "Engineering",
    "Date 1"     : "31/03/2005",
    "Date 2"     : "31/12/2022",
    "Paid"       : 134,
    "OS"         : 533
  },
  {
    "Category 1" : "Engineering",
    "Date 1"     : "31/03/2005",
    "Date 2"     : "31/12/2022",
    "Paid"       : 387,
    "OS"         : 4221
  },
  {
    "Category 1" : "Engineering",
    "Date 1"     : "31/12/2021",
    "Date 2"     : "31/03/2022",
    "Paid"       : 134,
    "OS"         : 533
  }
]
```

and we want to group the JSON objects in the outer array by the given category and the two dates to then compute the sum of the `Paid` and `OS` values for each group.

A possible XSLT 3 approach doing that with treating JSON as XDM arrays/maps is e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
                xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="map(*)*">
        <xsl:param name="maps" as="map(*)*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$maps" composite="yes" group-by=".('Category 1'), .('Date 1'), .('Date 2')">
            <xsl:sequence select=". => map:put('Paid', sum(current-group()?Paid)) => map:put('OS', sum(current-group()?OS))"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(map(*))]">
        <xsl:sequence
                select="array { mf:group(?*) }"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On Saxon's Java s9api level, to treat JSON as an `XdmValue` in the form of XDM arrays/maps, you can use `JsonBuilder` e.g.

```
Processor processor = new Processor(false);

JsonBuilder jsonBuilder = processor.newJsonBuilder();

XdmValue input = jsonBuilder.parseJson(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("sample1.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

That `XdmValue` can then serve as the input to the `applyTemplates` method of an `Xslt30Transformer`:

```
XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();

        
XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.compile(new StreamSource(new File("sheet1.xsl")));

        
Xslt30Transformer xslt30Transformer = xsltExecutable.load30();

        
xslt30Transformer.applyTemplates(input, xslt30Transformer.newSerializer(System.out));
```

The other way would be to use JSON input as the input to the XPath 3.1 function `json-to-xml`, transform the XML as needed and convert it back to JSON with `xml-to-json`; a sample stylesheet would be e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:param name="json-uri" as="xs:string"/>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:sequence select="$json-uri => unparsed-text() => json-to-xml() => mf:apply-templates() => xml-to-json(map{'indent':true()})"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="mf:apply-templates" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodes"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="array">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="map" composite="yes" group-by="string[@key = 'Category 1'], string[@key = 'Date 1'], string[@key = 'Date 2']">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="number[@key = ('Paid', 'OS')]" expand-text="yes">
        <number key="{@key}">{sum(current-group()/number[@key = current()/@key])}</number>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the Java API level I would suggest to pass the JSON file name or URI in as a parameter and run the code with `callTemplate` e.g.

```
Processor processor = new Processor(false);

XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();

XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.compile(new StreamSource(new File("sheet2.xsl")));

Xslt30Transformer xslt30Transformer = xsltExecutable.load30();

xslt30Transformer.setStylesheetParameters(Collections.singletonMap(new QName("json-uri"), new XdmAtomicValue("sample1.json")));

xslt30Transformer.callTemplate(null, xslt30Transformer.newSerializer(System.out));
```

The approach using the XML representation of JSON with `json-to-xml` and `xml-to-json` as an intermediary format is better at preserving the order of properties/items in JSON objects/XDM maps as e.g. its result is like

```
 [ 
  { "Category 1" : "Marine",
   "Date 1" : "31\/03\/2003",
   "Date 2" : "31\/12\/2021",
   "Paid" : 23,
   "OS" : 9 },
  
  { "Category 1" : "Marine",
   "Date 1" : "31\/12\/2021",
   "Date 2" : "31\/03\/2022",
   "Paid" : 2,
   "OS" : 5 },
  
  { "Category 1" : "Engineering",
   "Date 1" : "31\/03\/2005",
   "Date 2" : "31\/12\/2022",
   "Paid" : 521,
   "OS" : 4754 },
  
  { "Category 1" : "Engineering",
   "Date 1" : "31\/12\/2021",
   "Date 2" : "31\/03\/2022",
   "Paid" : 134,
   "OS" : 533 } ]
```

while the order is XDM map items if basically undefined so the result of the first sample is e.g.

```
[
  { "Date 2":"31\/12\/2021", "OS":9, "Paid":23, "Category 1":"Marine", "Date 1":"31\/03\/2003" },
  { "Date 2":"31\/03\/2022", "OS":5, "Paid":2, "Category 1":"Marine", "Date 1":"31\/12\/2021" },
  {
    "Date 2": "31\/12\/2022",
    "OS": 4754,
    "Paid": 521,
    "Category 1": "Engineering",
    "Date 1": "31\/03\/2005"
  },
  {
    "Date 2": "31\/03\/2022",
    "OS": 533,
    "Paid": 134,
    "Category 1": "Engineering",
    "Date 1": "31\/12\/2021"
  }
]
```

A full sample project is at https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonJson2JsonSaxon12Example1

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I have implemented it. But my json is as {
  "quiz": {
    "sport": {
      "q1": {
        "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
        "options": [
          "New York Bulls",
          "Los Angeles Kings",
          "Golden State Warriros",
          "Huston Rocket"
        ],
        "answer": "Huston Rocket"
      }
    }
      }
}
I want to fetch the value of some of the attribute. Please suggest.

Comment: Ask a new question about that particular input data, showing there in a well-formatted way both the JSON input you have and the JSON output you want and explaining how the approach shown here failed for you.