Unable to transform Json object to another json object with xslt in java
Sample json object for tarnsformation:
{
    "order": {
        "orderid": 1,
        "orderProps": [
            {
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2003",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2021",
                "Paid": 10,
                "OS": 4
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2003",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2021",
                "Paid": 13,
                "OS": 5
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31/12/2021",
                "Date 2": "31/03/2022",
                "Paid": 2,
                "OS": 5
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2005",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2022",
                "Paid": 134,
                "OS": 533
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2005",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2022",
                "Paid": 387,
                "OS": 4221
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31/12/2021",
                "Date 2": "31/03/2022",
                "Paid": 134,
                "OS": 533
            }
        ]
    }
}

Need transformed jsonobject in below format.
Out put json object after transformation:
{
    "order": {
        "orderid": 1,
        "orderProps": [
            {
                "Date 2": "31\/12\/2021",
                "OS": 9,
                "Paid": 23,
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31\/03\/2003"
            },
            {
                "Date 2": "31\/03\/2022",
                "OS": 5,
                "Paid": 2,
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31\/12\/2021"
            },
            {
                "Date 2": "31\/12\/2022",
                "OS": 4754,
                "Paid": 521,
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31\/03\/2005"
            },
            {
                "Date 2": "31\/03\/2022",
                "OS": 533,
                "Paid": 134,
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31\/12\/2021"
            }
        ]
    }
}

I have used below solution but that is only for json array.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75520901/how-to-transform-json-to-json-by-using-xslt-in-java#:~:text=XSLT%203.0%20has%20basically%20two,into%20the%20XML%20representation%20of

Both of your JSON objects share the same structure. It's not clear what you expect from the transformation. You can compare them using https://www.jsondiff.com/ and it would also probably help to read RFC 4627 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4627)

The transformation can be done on the JSON converted to the XML representation of XML the json-to-xml transformation gives and then to group some maps by there keys and sum the number values in each group, for explanation I first show the XML to XML transformation
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:variable name="transformed-json">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($json-input)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$transformed-json"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="array[@key = 'orderProps']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="map" composite="yes" group-by="string[@key = 'Category 1'], string[@key = 'Date 2'], string[@key = 'Date 1']">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="string[@key = 'Date 2'], string[@key = 'Category 1']"/>
          <number key="OS">{sum(current-group()/number[@key = 'OS'])}</number>
          <number key="Paid">{sum(current-group()/number[@key = 'Paid'])}</number>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="string[@key = 'Date 1']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="json-input" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">
{
    "order": {
        "orderid": 1,
        "orderProps": [
            {
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2003",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2021",
                "Paid": 10,
                "OS": 4
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2003",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2021",
                "Paid": 13,
                "OS": 5
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31/12/2021",
                "Date 2": "31/03/2022",
                "Paid": 2,
                "OS": 5
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2005",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2022",
                "Paid": 134,
                "OS": 533
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2005",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2022",
                "Paid": 387,
                "OS": 4221
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31/12/2021",
                "Date 2": "31/03/2022",
                "Paid": 134,
                "OS": 533
            }
        ]
    }
}
  </xsl:param>

</xsl:stylesheet>

which outputs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <map key="order">
      <number key="orderid">1</number>
      <array key="orderProps">
         <map>
            <string key="Date 2">31/12/2021</string>
            <string key="Category 1">Marine</string>
            <number key="OS">9</number>
            <number key="Paid">23</number>
            <string key="Date 1">31/03/2003</string>
         </map>
         <map>
            <string key="Date 2">31/03/2022</string>
            <string key="Category 1">Marine</string>
            <number key="OS">5</number>
            <number key="Paid">2</number>
            <string key="Date 1">31/12/2021</string>
         </map>
         <map>
            <string key="Date 2">31/12/2022</string>
            <string key="Category 1">Engineering</string>
            <number key="OS">4754</number>
            <number key="Paid">521</number>
            <string key="Date 1">31/03/2005</string>
         </map>
         <map>
            <string key="Date 2">31/03/2022</string>
            <string key="Category 1">Engineering</string>
            <number key="OS">533</number>
            <number key="Paid">134</number>
            <string key="Date 1">31/12/2021</string>
         </map>
      </array>
   </map>
</map>

, a slight change to convert that XML back to JSON with e.g.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:variable name="transformed-json">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($json-input)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$transformed-json => xml-to-json(map{ 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="array[@key = 'orderProps']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="map" composite="yes" group-by="string[@key = 'Category 1'], string[@key = 'Date 2'], string[@key = 'Date 1']">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="string[@key = 'Date 2'], string[@key = 'Category 1']"/>
          <number key="OS">{sum(current-group()/number[@key = 'OS'])}</number>
          <number key="Paid">{sum(current-group()/number[@key = 'Paid'])}</number>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="string[@key = 'Date 1']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="json-input" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">
{
    "order": {
        "orderid": 1,
        "orderProps": [
            {
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2003",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2021",
                "Paid": 10,
                "OS": 4
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2003",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2021",
                "Paid": 13,
                "OS": 5
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Marine",
                "Date 1": "31/12/2021",
                "Date 2": "31/03/2022",
                "Paid": 2,
                "OS": 5
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2005",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2022",
                "Paid": 134,
                "OS": 533
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31/03/2005",
                "Date 2": "31/12/2022",
                "Paid": 387,
                "OS": 4221
            },
            {
                "Category 1": "Engineering",
                "Date 1": "31/12/2021",
                "Date 2": "31/03/2022",
                "Paid": 134,
                "OS": 533
            }
        ]
    }
}
  </xsl:param>

</xsl:stylesheet>

then gives JSON output:
 { "order" : 
  { "orderid" : 1,
   "orderProps" : 
   [ 
    { "Date 2" : "31\/12\/2021",
     "Category 1" : "Marine",
     "OS" : 9,
     "Paid" : 23,
     "Date 1" : "31\/03\/2003" },
    
    { "Date 2" : "31\/03\/2022",
     "Category 1" : "Marine",
     "OS" : 5,
     "Paid" : 2,
     "Date 1" : "31\/12\/2021" },
    
    { "Date 2" : "31\/12\/2022",
     "Category 1" : "Engineering",
     "OS" : 4754,
     "Paid" : 521,
     "Date 1" : "31\/03\/2005" },
    
    { "Date 2" : "31\/03\/2022",
     "Category 1" : "Engineering",
     "OS" : 533,
     "Paid" : 134,
     "Date 1" : "31\/12\/2021" } ] } }

Both sample assume you pass in the JSON as a string as a global parameter to the stylesheet to be run with the initial template; for self-containedness I have inlined the JSON in both examples but in real life you could of course use e.g. <xsl:param name="json-input" as="xs:string" select="unparsed-text('input-file.json')"/> instead.
